# Neo4J OGM Session.load(ID) returns null object for existing ID

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-ogm

I am conducting some Neo4J tests and running into the following peculiar problem. I created a small model which I'm intending to use with OGM. The model has a superclass Entity and a child class Child. They're both in package `persistence.model`. Entity has the required `Long id;` with matching `getId()` getter.

```
public abstract class Entity {
   private Long id;
   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }
}

@NodeEntity
Child extends Entity {
   String name;
   public Child() {
   }
}
```

Creating Child objects and persisting them through OGM works fine. I'm basing myself on the examples found in the documentation and using a Neo4jSessionFactory object, which initialises the SessionFactory with the package `persistence.model`. The resulting database contains objects with proper ID's filled in.

The problem arises when I try to fetch a Child for a given ID. I'm trying it with three methods, using two connection systems (**bolt** and **ogm**):

```
boltSession.run("MATCH (a:Child) WHERE id(a) = {id} RETURN a", parameters("id", childId));

ogmSession.query("MATCH (a:Child) WHERE id(a) = $id RETURN a", params);

ogmSession.load(Child.class, childId, 1);
```

The first two methods actually return the correct data. The last one returns a null value. The last one, using OGM, has some obvious benefits, and I'd love to be able to use it properly. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a reproducible test case? I have tried exactly what you describe here - https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-sdn-ogm-issue-report-template/tree/so-44305093/so-44305093 and it works as expected (i.e. returns the node).

Comment: I created some test cases with minimal code here: https://github.com/CountZukula/neo4j-ogm-bug-test-case-template . Just add a single Child object in the database, modify the username/password in ogm.properties and Neo4JBolt.java and set the ID of the new object in the TestMain.java class. In my case, only the ogmLoad() test case fails. The two others succeed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test code you are doing a lookup by id of type `int`.

```
private int someIdInYourDatabase = 34617;
```

The internal ids in Neo4j are of type Long.

If you change the type of the id to `long` or `Long` then it will work.

```
private long someIdInYourDatabase = 34617;
```

Comment: I could have known it was something silly. Thank you for taking the time! As a sidenote: is there a valid reason why the java interface allows for any `ID` object to be passed to `session.load()`? Are other ID's possible besides `Long`s?

Comment: Yes, you can have a property annotated with `@Index(primary=true)`, e.g. of String type and you can then use session.load(x, "some string id") to lookup that by property.